# How to add file association during install with installshield 2012

Tags: file, installation, associations, installshield

I am trying to add file association during my installation process however the guide supplied doesn't seem to work.

I have used [the official Installshield help guide](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/AddingExtensions.htm) however this didn't work or add anything to the registry? The help guide was very basic and didn't mention what the verb argument does or how it should be used once you have added a new extension. (Not a very good help guide!).

Either way I understand that the registry holds a key that references the file extension and what should be done with it. Installshield appears to support what I am trying to do, however it just doesn't work? Could anyone suggest what the 'correct' process is for setting up a file extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an alternative method is to directly modify the registry with the values you need by using the registry change section within the installshield IDE. The appropriate registry keys can be created by adding a file association though windows and using this as a template of what to add to the registry.